# タグを追加するタイミングとはいつですか？

Tags: サポート

タグを追加するタイミングはいつでしょうか？
例えば、[os.path](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os.path)というのは、本家では248項目上がっています。今まで日本語版では出ていないようです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、日本語版では使わないように言われました。
こうしたタグを新しく追加するためには、あらかじめどなたかに許可を得なくてはならないのでしょうか？

Comment: 私が「乱用」を指摘したのは、python3.6.5 といったタグをつけることを目的としない限り発生しないものに対してです。念のため。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[os.path](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os.path)については、本家SOでは既に使われていることを確認せずに編集してしまった私の判断ミスでした(申し訳ありません…)。
質問を絞り込むのに必要だと思ったタグは、任意のタイミングで自由に追加してもらう形で基本的には大丈夫なはずです。

ただし、該当質問に恐らくPythonモジュールを想定して一緒に付けられていた[os](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os)と[spider](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spider)については、Pythonモジュールを指すよりもっと広い範囲でそれぞれ使われている単語なので、あまり適切では無いのかなと思いいったん外しました。本家SOではそれぞれ[operating-system](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operating-system)、[web-crawler](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler)への別名になっています。

Comment: いいえ、お気になさらないでください。私もいろいろと悪かったと思います。

Answer (score 4):

[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)には次のように書かれています:

> **どんなときに新しいタグを作成したらいいですか?**
>
> 成熟したサイトでは、たいていの一般的なタグはすでに存在します。常に既存のタグを優先してください。自分の質問がこのサイトで今までに他の人が誰も質問していない新しいトピックを対象と*している*と強く主張できる場合のみにしてください。

また [Meta Stack Exchange の FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949/341401) に書かれていることを和訳すると以下のようになります。

> **タグが作られるべきなのはどんなとき？**
>
> タグが作られるのは、その必要性が明らかであるときのみにすべきです。たとえば、そのサイトではそれまで質問されてこなかったものの、そのサイトでオントピックであるような新しい概念を表しているようなときです。たとえば本家 Stack Overflow では、もし新しいプログラミング言語が作られ広く使われるようになったがまだ誰もそれについて質問をしていないようなときには、その言語のためのタグを新しく作るべきです。
>
> **タグを作るべき*ではない*のはどんなとき？**
>
> タグを作るという目的のためだけにタグを作らないでください。可能な限り既存のタグを使うべきです。なぜなら、ユーザーは既存のタグに従ってタグ付けしますし、そうすることで良い回答を得る可能性が増えるからです。質問の内容ではなく質問の種類について説明しているようなタグ、通称[「メタ的なタグ」](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)を作ることは避けてください。意味が広くて曖昧なタグや、ある質問に単体で付けられないようなタグを作ることも避けてください。最後に、以前は存在していたがコミュニティの判断によって削除されたタグを作ることも避けてください。

Answer (score 3):

まず、本家 Stack Overflow にあるからといって日本語版にもそのタグが必要とは限らないと私は思います。日本語版で必要になったタグの名前を本家に揃えることはありますが、その逆は必ずしも成り立たないということです。このサイトで必要となったタグだけが作られるべきで、「本家にあるから」という理由だけで作られるのは不自然に感じます。

その上で、[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)に書かれている内容に沿う限り、自分が必要だと思ったタグを追加するのは自由で良いと思っています。それを見て「このタグは不要だろう」と思ったユーザーが他にいれば今回のように編集されたりメタで議論されたりします。また、作成から一定の間にあまり使われなかったタグは自動削除されるので、その意味で自然淘汰されることもあります。

今回の場合、[os.path](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os.path) というタグの作成を拒否する強い理由は思いつきません。ただしやや細かいタグですし、本家 Stack Overflow ですら 3 桁程度という比較的少ない数の質問にしかこのタグがついていないことを鑑みると、日本語版では自然淘汰されるかもなと思っています。